# What happened to Patsy and Delia?

Tags: call-the-midwife

In the episode where Barbara marries Tom (I don't know the season or episode number), at the end when everyone has gathered at the merry-go-round Tom hired after the wedding, Delia sees Patsy down the street. Patsy tells her that when her father died she came straight back and reassures Delia that where she goes next won't be without her. In the next episode neither one is in Nonnatus House.

Now I think I missed an episode or so because apparently Patsy had went missing or something and Delia had been trying to get in contact with her but I didn't get the sense that Patsy had formally left Nonnatus House and it's not that being gone for a while is any indicator, because Trixie had left for a while vacationing.

So following Barbara's and Tom's wedding, what happened to Patsy and Delia?

Answer (score 1):

[According to this Wikia page](https://callthemidwife.fandom.com/wiki/Patience_Mount):

> In Season Seven, its revealed that Patsy and Delia have gone travelling together.

[The real world reason](https://www.radiotimes.com/news/2018-11-13/call-the-midwife-stars-bryony-hannah-emerald-fennell-and-kate-lamb-wont-be-returning-for-series-seven/) for their absence is of course very prosaic:

> Call the Midwife is to lose Bryony Hannah, **Emerald Fennell and Kate Lamb** from the cast after **all three actors decided to quit the BBC1 drama**.